# Java Image Not Showing

Tags: java, image, swing, jlabel, embedded-resource

I'm trying to simply load a photo to jpanel but it is not working.

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.io.File;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ImageTest3 extends JFrame {

    public ImageTest3() {

        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        Icon icon = new ImageIcon(
                File.separator + "resources" 
                    + File.separator + "images"
                    + File.separator + "topbar.jpg");
        JLabel label1 = new JLabel();
        panel.add(label1);
        add(panel);
        label1.setIcon(icon);

        setSize(2000,700);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        new ImageTest3();
    }
}
```

Sorry for the crappy form... 
The file is saved in my `\src\resources\images\topbar.jpg`

What am I doing wrong ?
I also had it as `ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon` ....

Comment: I hope this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9866659/1057230) might be able to sort things out for you :-)

Comment: The info part of [embedded-resource](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info), can also point you in a better way.

Answer (score 0):

You should load the image as a Resource, as follows

```
String pathToImageSortBy = "resources"+File.separator+ "images"+ File.separator+"topbar.jpg";
Icon icon = newImageIcon(
                         getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(pathToImageSortBy));
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but I got a NullPointerException. The File is in the proper spot and the file name and such look correct. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you try putting a File.separator before "resources" ?

Comment: I guess the use of `getClassLoader()` is really not the right way, as suggested by the [Java Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/lang/resources.html) - __" If not found, the methods return null. A resource may be found in a different entry in the CLASSPATH than the location where the class file was loaded."__

Comment: You can also use a single slash instead of File.separator, since it is a resource

Comment: @christian That was my first response and still a null pointer

Comment: Are the class and the image on the same jar ?  If not, are both if them in the classpath ? I've made a test using same jar, and works

Comment: Yeah so i cant post a photo, Im not on my actual account. So I tried readding the photos. So .java files are ImageTest\src\defaultpackage\ImageTest3\ and the photos are  ImageTest\resources\images\topbar.jpg. ImageTest being the project name

Comment: On the readded i accidentally didnt put it in the \src\. That was probably the error. I dont know why it wasnt working before though

Comment: `File.separator` is the wrong char for `getResource()` - it should be `/` on all platforms.